# Pip3.5 points to old Python 3.4.2 after Python 3.5 installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed Python 3.5.4 alongside python 3.4.2.
Calling pip with python 3.4 works fine, that is:

```
>>pip3.4
>>py -3.4 -m pip
```

Trying to use the python 3.5 version of pip (which I have ticked to install during the installation) with:

```
>>pip
>>python -m pip
>>py -3.5 -m pip
```

All lead to this error:

```
Could not import runpy module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import importlib.machinery # importlib first so we can test #15386 via -m
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    _w_long = _bootstrap._w_long
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute '_w_long'
```

This is on a Windows 7 64bit PC. I have no idea why specifically calling the python 3.5 version of pip makes it to access python 3.4's directory as in "C:\Python3.4". Help?

Answer (score 0):

have you try to configure the environment variable properly?
See this link:
[python and pip windows configuration](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation)